# Idiomatic way of getting the key of the largest value in a BTreeMap?

Tags: algorithm, rust, btreemap

I need to get get the *key* associated with the largest *value* in a BTreeMap.  (Doing this the other way around is simple.)

My attempt so far is:

```
let mut opt_pair: Option<(&Foo, u32)> = None; 
for (key, value) in my_btreemap { // my_btreemap is known to be non-empty
    match opt_pair {
        Some(pair) => {
            if value > pair.1 {
                opt_pair = Some((key, value)); 
            }
        },
        None => {
            opt_pair = Some((key, value)); 
        }
    }
}

opt_pair.unwrap().0
```

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this, in a more functional style?

Comment: isn't this strange ? the search will be O(n)

Comment: Do you expect any specific behavior in case there are multiple "maximum"?

Comment: @trentcl Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Stargateur `my_btreemap` will usually contain 1-10 entries, so O(N) is fine.

Comment: @MatthieuM. IN the case of ties I don't care which is returned, so long as it is stable.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.iters) to get an [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) of each pair. Then call [`max_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by_key) on the iterator; this takes a closure to get the thing to compare.

```
let opt_pair = map
    .iter()                   // get an iterator over the tree
    .max_by_key( |p| p.1 )    // check the value of each pair for the max
    .unwrap();                // unwrap the result

println!("key: {}, value: {}", opt_pair.0, opt_pair.1);
```